# MarginTop between radio buttons for Different Screen Densities in Android

Tags: android-layout

Im trying to make a layout for a survey question, it works fine on my device but the margin between the radio button text decreases on a better screen resolution device.

I have tried creating different DIMENS it works but I'm not sure how to scale the margin based on different sizes.

Kindly suggests what screen size values-swXXX folder I need to create and what should be the scaling factor of the DIMEN I have defined.

Thanks

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="How often do you use it?"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rg_1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_1" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_once"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Once" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_daily"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rb_once"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
        android:text="Daily" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_weekly"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rb_daily"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
        android:text="Weekly" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_monthly"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rb_weekly"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
        android:text="Monthly" />
</RadioGroup>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fb_share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook_share" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/history"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fb_share"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/history" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fb_share"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/info" />



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fb_share"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rg_1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/red_btn"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto-Italic"
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create values-swXXXX folders wrt devices you are targetting for. i.e If you are targetting for a tablet with minimum width of 600, then you need to create values-sw600 and so on.

In layout file, change declaration of RadioButton as below:

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb_once"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
        android:button="@drawable/radio_btn"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Once" />
```

And maintain dimen.xml specific to each targeted dimension under values-swXXXX with dimension keys having same name but values corresponding to respective dimension. Ex:

```
 values/        
 <dimen name="left_margin">5dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="left_margin">10dp</dimen>

 values-sw600/      
 <dimen name="left_margin">20dp</dimen>
 <dimen name="left_margin">40dp</dimen>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. if we're not targeting tablets then can we make values-sw160, values-sw240, values-sw320 & values-sw480?

Comment: Technically it should work! But I haven't tested your scenario. Note that sw<width> is supported Android OS with version 3.2+ only.